# InnoDB Full-text indexes

Tags: mysql, innodb

I have just converted a table in my DB from MyISAM to InnoDB, mainly because I get better control of the Full Text Stop List with InnoDB. (I was caught out by MyISAM stopping the word 'want' which happened to be a surname!)
I read that InnoDB keeps a reverse index of the tokens in its own tables, but I can't find where this is. ?
I thought it might be in the Information_Schema DB but does not seem to be.
Also, when I did the change from MyISAM to InnoDB, should that have automatically generated the necessary indexes or do I have to manually cause a rebuild?

Comment: The table is part of information schema in innodb INFORMATION_SCHEMA.INNODB_FT_DEFAULT_STOPWORD , here is the official doc to create your own stopword list http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-stopwords.html, and for the 2nd part its always better to re-create the indexes after you have converted the table engine. Ideally the conversion should take care of it but just to be double sure.

Comment: I can see the default stop word list, but where are the actual indexes?

Comment: I dont think you can do some operation or see them like other tables, you can get some idea on how they are created using `SELECT table_id, name, space from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.INNODB_SYS_TABLES 
WHERE name LIKE %your table name%`

Comment: I think I might have an authorisation issue on the INFORMATION_SCHEMA DB ...  investigating

Comment: With file_per_table, the index will be in the .ibd file.

Comment: Sorry Rick, not sure what you mean? Does INFORMATION_SCHEMA have the same credentials for login as the actual DB?